# What is the gdb command for setting a breakpoint with gdb?

Tags: gdb, breakpoints

What is the gdb command for setting a breakpoint with gdb?
Could I set a breakpoint for a specific function, without supplying its line number as a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a breakpoint with the GNU Debugger with any of the following commands:

```
b <addr_or_function_symbol>
b <function name>
b *<instruction address>
b <filename:line number>
b <line number>
```

Note that the GDB must be initialized with a binary/file (obviously).